# How can I make Homebrew and CocoAspell coexist?

Tags: latex, homebrew, spell-checking, aspell, textmate2

After much searching on the Internet, I have never seen a satisfactory answer or explanation to the following problem. I would like to use CocoAspell for system-wide spell-checking on OS X 10.9 (plugs into TexShop, TextMate, etc.), but every time I install it, `brew doctor` starts throwing the following warnings:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libaspell.15.1.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpspell.15.1.4.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libaspell.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpspell.la
```

Internet searches have shown that these warnings never seem to lead to any errors, but it seems to me that there must be some way to suppress them. Partly, I like to see the `Your system is ready to brew` notification, but I'd also like to avoid some sort of "boy crying wolf" situation, where I become accustomed to `brew doctor` throwing errors.

Is there a way to either:

- Install CocoAspell in another location, such that `brew` doesn't see it
- Hide the offending dylib and .la files from `brew doctor`
- Or enable the CocoAspell preference pane/program to access libraries installed by a brewed version of `aspell`

Uninstalling CocoAspell and trashing the offending files results in a clean bill of health, and performing `brew install aspell` results in a working version of `aspell`, but this doesn't help me with any of the GUI applications I prefer for LaTeX editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Uninstall cocoAspell completely if you installed it before.
2. Install aspell with homebrew or any other package manager. Don't forget the dictionaries you need. I wanted English and Czech, so I used

   ```
   brew install aspell --with-lang-cs --with-lang-en
   ```
3. Install only the preference pane of cocoAspell. Click on "Customize" before installing and only select the "Spelling" option.
4. Create the directory `/Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/`
5. Make a symlink in the directory to make the preference pane aware of the available dictionaries (as the administrator):

   ```
   cd /Library/Application\ Support/cocoAspell/
   ln -s /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60 Dictionaries
   ```

   Make sure that `/usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60` is the correct path.
6. The cocoAspell pref pane now shows the installed dictionaries.

Comment: Much better than white-listing. Have to add this into my setup script for new machines.

Answer (score 0):

Add the offending files to the `white_list` in `doctor.rb`. Mine was in `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb`

If your's isn't there, find it with

```
locate doctor.rb
```

Look for white_list in side of `def check_for_stray_dylibs`, mine was on line 105. It should probably look like this.

```
white_list = {
  "libfuse.2.dylib" => "MacFuse",
  "libfuse_ino64.2.dylib" => "MacFuse",
  "/usr/local/lib/libTrAPI.dylib" => "TrAPI"
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there an etiquette associated with doing this and committing the changes to Homebrew? I'm still learning the ins and outs of git and distributed versioning… When I apply these changes, `brew doctor` complains that I'm out of sync with the main repository.

Comment: They have a [Contributing.md](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) file on their github page, thats the right place to start in general. I'd think that they'd be happy with a [feature request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues) for a white_list thats not inside of doctor.rb

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to install Homebrew somewhere other than `/usr/local` (that is, create `~/.homebrew`, or `/Tools/homebrew`; then `sudo chmod $USER /Tools/homebrew`, untar Homebrew there, and add `/Tools/homebrew/bin` to your `$PATH`).  That way, `/usr/local` is reserved for things you're installed there by some other means, rather than using Homebrew; for example the situation you describe here.  Homebrew still occasionally whines about it, but you can usually ignore it.

I use Homebrew as my principal OS X package manager; I don't let it anywhere near `/usr/local`.

Note that this advice is the direct opposite of [Homebrew's insistent dogma](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-insist-i-install-to-usrlocal-with-such-vehemence), which I myself find unpersuasive.